# Алгоритм для рисования схемы сети.

Tags: алгоритм, сеть, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго всем времени суток. У меня такой вопрос: требуется отпарсить некие логи с OSPF маршрутизатора в сети и нарисовать схему сети по ним. Подскажите пожалуйста рациональный алгоритм рисования, т.к. заранее неизвестны размеры сети, кол-во маршрутизаторов и т.д. Т.е. мне нужно определить с какого роутера начинать рисовать, каким макаром дорисовывать к нему остальные, ну и прочее.

Answer (score 4):

я бы использовал [graphviz](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz). Ваш скрипт должен пропарсить все и сгенерировать файл вида

```
digraph G{
    "router"->"comp1";
    "router"->"comp2";
    "comp1"->"comp2";
}
```

и так далее. а уже сам graphviz построит граф. 
онлайн можно испытать [здесь](http://sandbox.kidstrythisathome.com/erdos/index.html).

Все хорошо настраиваться и кастомизируется.

Comment: Хорошая штука. Если не срастется с самостоятельной реализацией, то сделаю через нее)

Comment: там можно и не только чернобелые кружочки рисовать. А и разноцветные квадраты, эллипсы и [свои картинки](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073115/how-do-i-get-dot-to-display-an-image-for-a-node).

Comment: О, спасибо, буду знать.